# Scope crafication problem with c struct in class

Tags: c++, sockets, scope

I am trying to write the socket part of a larger program. I have a class in which everything happens. The problem is that is get a scope (probably) error I do not understand.

My header file is:

```
namespace aaa{
namespace bbb{
class myclass {
public:
  myclass();
  ~myclass();
  ...
  struct addrinfo* addressInfo;
};}}
```

The destructor I have is:

```
namespace aaa{
namespace bbb{
...
myclass::~myclass() {
  if ( addressInfo != NULL)
    freeaddrinfo(addressInfo);
  if ( socketDescriptor > 0 )
    close(socketDescriptor);
  free(buffer);
}
...
}}
```

When trying to compile I get an error stating:

```
error: cannot convert ‘aaa::bbb::addrinfo*’ to ‘addrinfo*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void freeaddrinfo(addrinfo*)’
freeaddrinfo(myclass::addressInfo);
                                 ^
```

Any suggestions would be great, I cannot get anything out of google.

Comment: Did you include the header containing the declaration of the `addrinfo`? BTW, in C++ you don't have to say `struct addrinfo *`, can just use `addrinfo`.

Comment: I do indeed include the header file and have the usual #IFNDEF in the header.

Comment: can you remove `struct` from `addrinfo` and see if the compiler output changes (or best paste the declaration of the struct and freeaddrinfo from the header file just above the class, so we could play with it in godbolt

Comment: I think "crafication" is not the word you're looking for, but I'm unable to guess what word you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your member variable declaration is equivalent to

```
class myclass
{
    struct addrinfo;
    addrinfo* addressInfo;
};
```

which declares the type `myclass::addrinfo`, not a global type.

You can forward-declare the type in the global scope:

```
struct addrinfo;

namespace aaa{
namespace bbb{
class myclass {
public:
  //...
  addrinfo* addressInfo; // No 'struct' here.
};
}
}
```

or, if the type is already declared in the global scope, you can just drop the `struct`.

Comment: Actually I could not drop the "struct", but eventually found my error. I will vote your answer because it points to the correct direction. I did not had the inclusion of netdb.h in the header but in the source file, which meant that indeed my struct addrinfo* was a declaration. With the correct inclusions everything work.